# Create drop downs to select categories - Magento CE 1.8.1.0

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento-1.8

- Removed - Caused Confusion

*** EDIT ***

I want to create drop down list that would be used to navigate a specific category tree.

Here is a visual aid that may help some:
http://www.colorblastpowders.com/sample-drop-downs.png

*** EDIT ***

Still looking for an answer, unfortunately I am not a strong programmer and cannot do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "year/made/model" extension

there are many existing extension on the web
e.g.
http://vehiclefits.com/

But be aware of that most of them has their own database table to store the relation, if you just save the product, it wont add the relation by auto. Instead, you have to import by yourselves.

Comment: Hello Leo, I realize there are extensions that do that, but they almost always require a separate db of the fitment, when in reality it is not needed. that is why I want to do it this way. Thank you for the suggestion.